# Does one get rep for helpful flags

Tags: support, editing, flagging

It is not so much that I am worried about rep, but I like to understand.
I actually had 2 rep point on a question that was migrated, and as far as I can recall or trace on the question, my only contribution was to flag it. I though I might have done an edit, but it does not show on the migrated editing history.

The question is now totally removed from TCS (so I lost the 2 rep). Would that affect the editing history on the migrated version?   ... at the risk of some historical inconsistency?

I am interested because I flagged the question, then closed, to have it migrated. If I got 2 rep for flagging it, to later lose them because what I asked has been done, that would be rather amusing.

Comment: afaik some of the history resets when posts are migrated. your prior established rep can change (sometimes downward) based on new actions on old posts. its a little counterintuitive at 1st.

Comment: @vzn Thanks.  I just found the explanation. It is in an answer below.  First problem was to set my memory right.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that giving flags should not affect reputation.  You can look at the reputation rules here: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Thanks. Of course, I did look first. But my experience is that some rules are not always too explicit (may be located somewhere else). Then, the remainig explanation is that editing history is modified when a migrated page is fully removed from its original site ... how else (than editing the question) could I have received 2 rep ?  ... still trying to understand where they came from.   ...  **just found the explanation**: history is edited out.

Answer (score 0):

By looking again at the history of the question on its new site, I finally remembered I had edited the question.  Not changing the text, but changing the tags so that it would be seen by the right people. That gave me the 2 rep.

I checked on another question where I had done the same: it is indeed recorded in the editing history. Apparently, **on the new site, a migrated question starts again from its current editing state, with a blank editing history.**

and ... (I just found out)

**Its former editing history is indeed kept in the original site** (here TCS), but is accessible only from the new site (migration site) from the migration information blurb. And, I am guessing, it can still be read when one has enough rep. But it cannot be accessed from the original site after question removal.

It remains funny that I deprived myself of 2 rep for successfully suggesting migration in my flag. But no regrets.

Still, I am not sure administrative rep should be lost when a question is removed: it is still a contribution. It makes more sense to remove rep acquired from votes on content, as removal should be motivated by the fact that content is not worth much. But I guess it is just too complicated to make a difference.

Comment: wish there was more info on what happens during migrations, it is not simple, it is a relatively newer feature of stackexchange grafted onto existing mechanisms and has many awkward aspects esp from all pts of view (asker, answerers, mods, etc). iirc sometimes comments are deleted, sometimes not. also, sometimes it seems they maybe dont start out at zero votes after migration etc. iirc sometimes they start out with positive votes. etc... ... re rep, it makes no sense to think much about small fluctuations in rep, eg note anyone can instantly cause -2 on any of your existing answers...

Comment: Of course, small rep fluctuations in rep do not matter. Actually the
meaning of SE rep is very disputable. But I have a vice: I need to
understand (hence my interest in sciences). And I have some principles
regarding the preservation of history, or the consistency of systems.